# How to close SYS_REF CURSOR in oracle pl/sql?

Tags: plsql

I can't compile this `pl/sql`. I am not familiar with `pl/sql` and I want to `close c_cur` after using it.

```
create or replace
procedure GET_INSPECTION_CALL_REF_NO (
    in_vendor_code varchar2,
    c_cur out SYS_REFCURSOR
)
is
    declare
        c_cur is 
            select call_log_id, call_log_ref_no
            from INSPECTION_CALL_LOG
            where modified_by = in_vendor_code;

        var_c_cur c_cur%ROWTYPE;
    begin
        open c_cur;
        loop 
            fetch c_cur into var_c_cur
            exit when c_cur%notfound;
        end loop;
        close c_cur;
    end;
end GET_INSPECTION_CALL_REF_NO;
```

Comment: what error message u r getting??

Comment: Error(7,1): PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "DECLARE" when expecting one of the following:     begin function package pragma procedure subtype type use    <an identifier> <a double-quoted delimited-identifier> form    current cursor external language The symbol "cursor was inserted before "DECLARE" to continue.

Comment: Error(16,1): PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "EXIT" when expecting one of the following:     . ( , % ; limit

Comment: Try this. just add ";" at the end of Fetch. Also there are two End statement at last remove one. But still i am not understanding what your are trying to do with this stored procedure .

Comment: Error(10,1): PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "DECLARE" when expecting one of the following:     begin function package pragma procedure subtype type use    <an identifier> <a double-quoted delimited-identifier> form    current cursor external language The symbol "cursor was inserted before "DECLARE" to continue.

Comment: c_cur u have declared inside stored procedure and also u have used as out parameter ..  Logically its wrong. what is ur requirement ? '

Answer (score 0):

You can rewrite your procedure like,

```
create or replace
procedure GET_INSPECTION_CALL_REF_NO (
    in_vendor_code varchar2,
    c_cur out SYS_REFCURSOR
)
as 
    v_call_log_id  INSPECTION_CALL_LOG.call_log_id%type; 
    v_call_log_ref_no  INSPECTION_CALL_LOG.call_log_ref_no%type;
begin
    open c_cur for 
    select call_log_id, call_log_ref_no
    from INSPECTION_CALL_LOG
    where modified_by = in_vendor_code;

    loop 
        fetch c_cur into v_call_log_id, v_call_log_ref_no;
        exit when c_cur%notfound;
    end loop;

    close c_cur; --really needed here???
end GET_INSPECTION_CALL_REF_NO;
```

> A REF CURSOR is a PL/SQL data type whose value is the memory address
>   of a query work area on the database. In essence, a REF CURSOR is a
>   pointer or a handle to a result set on the database

Here you are using the `ref-cursor` to return the result hence no point in `closing the cursor`.

Its the duty of the caller of this proc to close the cursor.

You cannot do `var_c_cur c_cur%ROWTYPE;` on `ref-cursor`
You have to use `table.column%type` or `DBMS_SQL` package.

This procedure can be rewritten to ,

```
create or replace
procedure GET_INSPECTION_CALL_REF_NO (
    in_vendor_code varchar2,
    c_cur out SYS_REFCURSOR
)
as
begin
    open c_cur for 
    select call_log_id, call_log_ref_no
    from INSPECTION_CALL_LOG
    where modified_by = in_vendor_code;
end GET_INSPECTION_CALL_REF_NO;
```

Closing the `Ref-Cursor`;

```
DECLARE
    v_cur  SYS_REFCURSOR;
    v_call_log_id  INSPECTION_CALL_LOG.call_log_id%type; 
    v_call_log_ref_no  INSPECTION_CALL_LOG.call_log_ref_no%type;
BEGIN
    GET_INSPECTION_CALL_REF_NO('some_code', v_cur);

    loop 
        fetch c_cur into v_call_log_id, v_call_log_ref_no;
        exit when c_cur%notfound;
        -- Use v_call_log_id, and v_call_log_ref_no...
    end loop;
  CLOSE v_cur; --Please note.
END;
/
```

Comment: actually i get 'maximum cursors exceeded oracle error' when i change data of combo box very fast ,i also close database connection yet i get this error,that's why i want to close cursor.

Comment: if i want to get data from multiple table using join query ,i have to declare every field name in DECLARE with  %type   ? please help

Comment: If you clode the cursor in the procedure, you will get invalid cur error when someone call that proc.  See where these procedures are used. try to close the cursor where it is used.

Comment: See `DBMS_SQL` package or you have to declare each column with either `%type` or corresponding datatyepe, `%type` is prefferd